# Using WCF DLL with VB6?

Tags: wcf, vb6, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a VB6 application that needs to communicate with a VS2008 VB.NET WCF server. I have built a VB.NET WCF DLL to be used on the client side, and it --almost-- works with the VB6 application.  When I try to run the VB6 app in debug mode, I get "Could not find endpoint element with name 'NetTCPBinding_IComPortManager' and contract 'IComPortManager' in the ServiceModel client configuration section." Using a dummy VB.Net client app, with the same WCF DLL works fine. I presume that the VB6 app/WCF DLL is not finding app.config. Where should app.config be ? Is there a way to tell WCF where to find app.config ?

Answer (score 1):

The app.config should be named as if your host was a .NET app, i.e.

> YourAppName.exe.config

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240873/trace-not-working-in-a-net-dll-loaded-from-vb6-exe/2445073#2445073) describes all the issues regarding VB6 and exe.config files.