# VB6 IDE crashes on run for all projects / vb6 compiled programs crash on start

Tags: windows, vb6

Windows 10 updates are current.  The problem began in late February. The VB IDE crashed after the first code line was accessed in a form, class or usercontrol. Until recently I was able to compile and successfully run new builds. A few days ago all vb6 exe, dll and ocx components fail with a similar error to the attached example. All projects I have tested throw similar errors.

VB6 has been uninstalled with RevoUninstaller Pro and reinstalled. No Add-ins are enabled.
Tried the fixes suggested on these links and others:

[VB6 App + .Net component working as compiled app but not in VB6 IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855125/vb6-app-net-component-working-as-compiled-app-but-not-in-vb6-ide)

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?824971-RESOLVED-VB6-IDE-Crashes

Ran the VB6 project from VB.net as an attached project

```
'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.

'VB6.EXE' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbol loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
```

The program '[13048] VB6.EXE' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

---

### Application Error Logs

.NET Runtime

Application: vb6.exe

Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 0B37CDC4

Stack:

Event ID 1026

---

Application Error

Faulting application name: vb6.exe, version: 6.0.97.82, time stamp: 0x403acf6c

Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0b37cdc4

Faulting process id: 0x40e8

Faulting application start time: 0x01d60ab183145008

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\vb6.exe

Faulting module path: unknown

Report Id: 5fafeb87-20bd-4f77-9a5a-bae6cde24b3f

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

Event ID 1000

---

Windows Error Reporting

Fault bucket 1831968984321653209, type 5

Event Name: BEX

Response: Not available

Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:

P1: vb6.exe

P2: 6.0.97.82

P3: 403acf6c

P4: StackHash_c527

P5: 0.0.0.0

P6: 00000000

P7: PCH_31_FROM_ntdll+0x0007232C

P8: c0000005

P9: 00000008

P10:

Attached files:

```
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1B87.tmp.dmp

\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1CE0.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1D00.tmp.xml

\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1D02.tmp.csv

\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1D32.tmp.txt
```

These files may be available here:

```
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_vb6.exe_47b3ce96ec8d67441c3dbcc33d366b2d17b8924_8195a9fa_a7a50a1f-0fa8-4959-9011-91d4cb568f8b
```

Analysis symbol:

Rechecking for solution: 0

Report Id: 5fafeb87-20bd-4f77-9a5a-bae6cde24b3f

Report Status: 268435456

Hashed bucket: 79303f7733d2cbc7496c7615c60679d9

d

Comment: "VB6 has been uninstalled with RevoUninstaller Pro" -- why would you do that? Standard Add/Remove Programs in control panel is not working? "Ran the VB6 project from VB.net as an attached project" -- why would you do that? You want to peek at the disassembly and patch some error VB6 creators made? Try installing VB6 on a different PC or in a VM on the same PC. Probably you have issues with your Windows OS going on for some time now.

Comment: @wqw sounds like he has some .NET interop going on; possibly the main program is a VB6 EXE and it has to load some .NET DLLs. So you start off by running in the .NET IDE which in turns loads VB6 IDE.

Comment: If you start a brand new VB6 project from the VB6 IDE - no .NET or anything else, does that also crash?

Comment: uninstall ensuring existing registry items is recommended
http://blog.danbrust.net/2015/09/14/installing-visual-basic-studio-6-on-windows-10/ 

A new project fails. A project created in a VM runs. 

VB project opened from VB.NET attach offers no information other than
The program '[13048] VB6.EXE' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: resolved with windows update installation